VSCode How to stop a plugin from adding the the "outline sidebar"
I use VSCode as a PHP developer.
I have PHP Intelephense, which is just awesome for code completion and etc.
The only problem I have with this plugin is its implementation into the outline sidebar, if your working on messy projects, or very outdated PHP code like we have to all the time, it ends up a bit flakey and doesn't work correctly.
So a while ago I found an alternative plugin called PHP Symbols, this plugin works absolutely perfectly in the outline sidebar and never lets me down.
But my problem for a while now is both Intelephense and PHP Symbols are showing in the outline view, I want to disable Intelephense from this view, but retain its other functionality.
Intelephense and PHP Symbols shown in outline
I've tried in vein to find out how to do this and just cant seem to find any solution, does anyone know?

if there isn't an extension-specific setting for this, you might need to feature-request one in the extension's issue tracker. if you do, please add a link here to your ticket.
